# How to eliminate the boilerplate of wrapping and unwrapping using lenses

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens, lenses, newtype

**tl;dr**: is it possible to use any of the `lens` family of abstractions to wrap/unwrap any arbitrary `newtype` (that provides an instance for such abstractions)?

I'll motivate my question by a simple example, based on a true story. Suppose I define the following `newtype`:

```
newtype FreeMonoid a = FreeMonoid { asMap :: Map a Int }
```

which is used to represent terms of the form:

```
a0 <> a1 <> ... <> an-1
```

We can represent free-monoids as lists:

```
instance Ord a => IsList (FreeMonoid a) where
    type Item (FreeMonoid a) = a
    fromList xs = FreeMonoid $ Map.fromListWith (+) $ zip xs (repeat 1)
    toList (FreeMonoid p) = do
        (x, n) <- Map.toList p
        genericReplicate n x
```

Two examples of free-monoids are sequences of sum and sequences of products:

```
type FreeSum a = FreeMonoid (Sum a)
type FreeProduct a = FreeMonoid (Product a)
```

Where `Sum` and `Product` are defined in [`Data.Monoid`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html). Now we could define `fromList` and `toList` operations for `FreeSum` and
`FreeProduct` as follows:

```
fromListSum :: Ord a => [a] -> FreeSum a
fromListSum = fromList . (Sum <$>)

fromListProduct :: Ord a => [a] -> FreeProduct a
fromListProduct = fromList . (Product <$>)
```

But this has quite a lot of boilerplate. It'd be nicer if we could simply say:

```
fromListW :: (Ord a, Wrapper f) => [a] -> FreeMonoid (f a)
fromListW = fromList . (wrap <$>)
```

where `wrap` is some operation of the (hypotetical) `Wrapper` class were:

```
wrap :: a -> f a
unwrap :: f a -> a
```

Similarly, I'd like to be able to write a function:

```
toListW :: (Ord a, Wrapper f) => FreeMonoid (f a) -> [a]
toListW = (unwrap <$>) . toList
```

Lenses seem to provide such an abstraction in [`Control.Lens.Wrapped`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.4/docs/Control-Lens-Wrapped.html) (for which `Sum` and `Product` in this example are instances of the typeclasses there!). However my attempts to understand and use the abstractions in this module have failed. For instance:

```
fromListW :: (Ord a, Wrapped (f a))  => [a] -> FreeMonoid (f a)
fromListW = fromList . (Wrapped <$>)
```

won't work since the argument is not a list of `Unwrapped (f a)`.

So my question is:

- Do lenses provide an abstraction similar to this `Wrapper` class?
- If not, can this "scrap-your-boilerplate" problem be solved by using lenses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "problem" is that you're using `Wrapped`, which is really meant to be a convenience pattern synonym and not a wrapping "constructor".  Because it's designed to support polymorphic wrapping, you need to assert that your type can be rewrapped:

```
fromListW :: (Rewrapped a a, Ord a) => [Unwrapped a] -> FreeMonoid a
fromListW = fromList . (Wrapped <$>)
```

This then works as expected:

```
> let x = [1,2,3]
> fromListW x :: FreeMonoid (Sum Int)
FreeMonoid {asMap = fromList [(Sum {getSum = 1},...
> fromListW x :: FreeMonoid (Product Int)
FreeMonoid {asMap = fromList [(Product {getProduct = 1},...
>
```

I think a more idiomatic lens implementation would be:

```
fromListW :: (Rewrapped a a, Ord a) => [Unwrapped a] -> FreeMonoid a
fromListW = fromList . view (mapping _Unwrapped)
```

This still requires the `Rewrapped a a` constraint, but you can use the non-polymorphic `_Unwrapped'` instead:

```
fromListW :: (Wrapped a, Ord a) => [Unwrapped a] -> FreeMonoid a
fromListW = fromList . view (mapping _Unwrapped')
```

which looks a little more natural.

The `toListW` implementation would have similar structure:

```
toListW :: (Wrapped a, Ord a) => FreeMonoid a -> [Unwrapped a]
toListW = view (mapping _Wrapped') . toList
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. It is still unclear how and why the solution works, but I hope that understanding will come after I dive deeper into lenses. In the meantime [here](https://github.com/capitanbatata/sandbox/blob/master/pw-lenses/src/Coercions.lhs) is some working code.